# what does datediff in tsql return

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql which returns the date of last monday.

```
SELECT  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0) //2017-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

However in trying to understand how this has been worked out, I'm confused 
 as to what the 6124 returned by the following represents

```
 SELECT  DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE())
```

It's only last week why is it such a high number?

Also how can the offset be a fixed number and still be able to work out the date of the previous monday

Answer (score 0):

That's sunday of Jan of 1900...

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(wk, '1/1/1900','5/20/2017'),
DATEDIFF(wk, '1/1/1900',GETDATE())
```

Specifically, they are using [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) instead of an actual `DATETIME` which is an acceptable parameter of [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

So to answer you question, that's the number of weeks (since you specified wk) from the first Sunday in January 1900 to the current day.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `6` for `startdate` in the `datediff` is just another way to reduce the output by one week, so it returns how many weeks since `1900-01-06` instead of `1900-01-01` (difference of one).

These two statements will return the same result:

```
select dateadd(week, datediff(week, 6, getdate()),0)
select dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate())-1,0)
```

Just this part: `datediff(week, 6, getdate()` returns the number of weeks (6,124) since `1900-01-06` which when added to a date of `1900-01-01` gives you the start of last week.